# How to use regex in Selenium IDE target?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I have to validate current date in my test case with Selenium IDE and I research for a regular expression or a function to insert directly in my `.side` file to verify the date.

[image]
I tried to put regexp:`(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)` (and other basic regex) in value or in target with verify text command and assert text command ..

But these are all not working...

So Please help me...

Comment: what date format you are using? Regex will be used in value column

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not the best way to check, but I use it in my tests.

```
Command | Target | Value 
store text | css=.vigor-title | date 
execute script | var date = ${date}; var regexp = new RegExp('(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)'); return regexp.test(date); | result 
assert | result | true
```